# Need To Assign My Vendor's ID To InvoiceTable - One To Many Relationship

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, vuejs2, laravel-5.7

I'm using `Laravel 5.7` & `VueJs 2.5.*` ...

I have a `TicketInvoice` and each `TicketInvoice` is related to a `Vendor`. Like a `Vendor` `hasMany()` `TicketInvoices` and a TicketInvoice `belongTo()` a `Vendor`.

Now the issue i'm getting is when i create my invoice, i have a list of `Vendors`, i need to select the vendor from the list, and assign `vendor_id` in the `TicketInvoiceTable`, I have a column `vendor_id` in `TicketInvoicetable`, I don't know how to do that but i'm doing like:

Here is my `HTML` code:

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="vendor">Select Vendor</label>
  <select id="vendor_id" name="vendor_id" type="text" class="form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('vendor_id')}">
    <option disabled selected>Please Select Vendor</option>
    <option v-for="vendor in vendors" :key="vendor.id" :value="vendor.vendor_id">{{ vendor.vendor_company_name }}</option>
  </select>
  <has-error :form="form" field="vendor_id"></has-error>
</div>
```

Here is my `VueJs` Code:

```js
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        ticketInvoices: {},
        vendors: null,
        form: new Form({
          id: "",
          vendor_id: "",
          ticket_invoice_no: "",
          ticket_invoice_date: "",
          ticket_invoice_fares_total: "",
          ticket_invoice_grand_total: "",

          ticketInvoiceItems: [{
            id: "",
            ticket_invoice_id: "",
            passenger_name: "",
            ticket_no: "",
            departure_date: "",
            fares: "",
            sub_total: ""
          }]
        })
      };
    },
    methods: {
      createTicketInvoice() {
        this.form
          .post("api/ticket-invoice")
          .then(() => {
            $("#addNewTicketInvoice").modal("hide");
          });
      })
    .catch(() => {
      swal("Failed!", "There was something wrong.", "warning");
    });
  },
  loadVendors() {
    axios.get("api/vendor").then(({
      data
    }) => (this.vendors = data.data));
  }, 
  </script>
```

Here is an image for better understanding:
[image: Create Invoice Form With Vendor's List]

Comment: So does it work, or do you get an error? If so where? Your primary key on vendor is vendor_id? Otherwise that would be  just vendor.id just like you reference it for the key.

Comment: Yes i get an error while i submit my form, `vendor_id` cannot be null. @Anders

Comment: Ok, and vendor.vendor_id is not null? Because right before that you reference vendor.id - which is the normal naming convention. What if you replace vendor.vendor_id with vendor.id?

Comment: Yes! this is also a mistake i corrected it. Thanks for your time @Anders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah ! I got my answer:

The `v-model` tag needs to refer to the object in my data in the Vue Component:

```html
<select id="vendor_id" name="vendor_id" v-model="form.vendor_id" type="text" class="form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('vendor_id')}">
  <option disabled selected>Please Select Vendor</option>
  <option v-for="vendor in vendors" :key="vendor.id" :value="vendor.id">{{ vendor.vendor_company_name }}</option>
</select>
```